# Issues using position_dodge()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble with position_dodge, when using colours and shapes.

I want to graph results from an experiment in which two treatments are replicated at many sites and I would like to emphasize certain data points graphically.

As the x-axis is a factor, I'd used position_dodge, to separate the treatments. So far so good, see graph 1 below.

However, if I want to emphasize a particular data point by changing the shape, see graph 2. The data points have now been split into three columns, not the two.

Any suggestions on how I would make a graph as pictured in the third panel below.

```
site <- rep(c("site1"),times=6) 
treatment <- rep(c("one","two"),times=2,each=3) 
set.seed(21)
response <- c(rnorm(3,mean=4),
              rnorm(3,mean=5))

special <- as.factor(c(0,1,0,0,0,0))

mydata <- data.frame(site,treatment,response,special)

#graph 1
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=mydata,
             aes(x = site,
                y = response,
                colour=treatment),
             size=4,
             position=position_dodge(1))

#graph 2
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=mydata,
             aes(x = site,
                 y = response,
                 colour=treatment,
                 shape=special),
             size=4,
             position=position_dodge(0.5))
```

[image: ![example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vpH4uYlqTp7J9Wr8Ma1fwuYrNFtegDdG)]

Comment: Add `group = treatment` to your `aes`.

Comment: Thats it. Thank you!